# How to organize folder structure for a Firebase functions + VueJS Project?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

I started a firebase project with the following folder structure:

```
.firebase
functions/
   node_modules/
   .eslintrc.json
   index.js
   package-lock.json
   package.json
public/
   index.html
.firebaserc
.gitignore
firebase.json
```

Since I want to integrate VueJS to it, I moved `node_modules/`, `package-lock.json`, `package.json` and `eslintrc.json` to the ROOT folder.

After I did that I had to add the following to the `functions` attribute in `firebase.json`:
    "source": "functions"

When I run `firebase serve` everything works great. However, when I try to `firebase deploy` an error message raises:

```
Error: No npm package found in functions source directory. Please run 'npm init' inside functions
```

How is the best way to organize my project to properly integrate Functions and Vue?

Please do not tell me that I should have two `package.json`

Comment: What's wrong with two package.json?  I can't imagine that you'd want to mix up your frontend and backend modules into a single module with a single package.json.

Comment: @DougStevenson, probably I didn't want it because I come from a RoR world, where projects have a single Gemfile for Frontend and Backend.
I clarified concepts by reading https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules.
If somebody has a folder structure suggestion for this particular integration, it is welcomed.

Comment: Yeah, that's not the way it works.  Maybe pick another framework that does what you're suggesting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, I'm sticking with Vue, using its default folder structure and adding a functions folder